# How to split a stream to stdout+stderr based on regular expression pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, maven, stream

I have a tool that outputs everything to one stream. The tool is Apache Maven. The stream looks like:

```
[INFO] ...
[INFO] ...
[WARNING] ...
[ERROR] ...
```

I want to split it into two streams, where the second one (stderr) will get all lines that start with `[ERROR]` and the first one (stdout) will get the rest:

```
$ mvn | splitter "^\[ERROR\]" 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

Is there an out-of-the-box tool in Linux that can help? Or I have to write a custom script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything out of the box that does this, but it's a very simple script:

```
errorRE=$1
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $errorRE ]]
    then printf "%s" "$line" >&2
    else printf "%s" "$line"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing a script is easy. You just have to compare line by line:

```
mvn | awk '/^\[ERROR\]/ { print  > "/dev/stderr"; next; }; 1'
```

Bash:

```
mvn | while IFS= read -r LINE; do [[ $LINE == '[ERROR]'* ]] && { echo "$LINE" >&2; continue; }; echo "$LINE"; done
```

As a function:

```
function splitter {
    local IFS= LINE
    while read -r LINE; do
        [[ $LINE == '[ERROR]'* ]] && {
             echo "$LINE" >&2
             continue
        }
        echo "$LINE"
    done
}

mvn | splitter
```

You could save the function as a part of a script and source it `. splitter.sh` or save it in an rc file like `~/.bashrc` at your preference.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache Maven 3.1 the logging framework has been changed. Read http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html for all the details.
So if a logger can split the output in different files, so can Maven.